# Error trying to execute Oracle stored procedure in Django

Tags: django, stored-procedures, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a Django app where I have to execute some stored procedures. My database is an Oracle 11g.

I need to pass the date as argument to the stored procedure and I get some error converting the string date from the template to the Django view:

**Model:**

```
class HOMEDAC():
      def concidac(self, pv_fecha):
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          spdac = cursor.callproc("django_sp.home_dac",(pv_fecha))
          cursor.close()
          return spdac
```

**View**

```
def ProcedureView(request):
    form = DACForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.is_valid():
          f = request.POST.get('fecha')
          pfec = datetime.datetime.strptime(f,'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
          carga = HOMEDAC()
          sp = carga.concidac(pfec)
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    return render_to_response('dac.html',{'form':form})
```

**HTML Template:**

```
<head>
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();
     });
     </script>

  </head>
<body >

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
    <form method='POST' role="form">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        {% crispy form %}
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
</body>
```

**Form:**

```
class DACForm(forms.Form):
      fecha = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),)
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(DACForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper()
          self.helper.form_method = 'post'
          self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

I get the error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'HOME_DAC'
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I know this is error is triggered when you don't pass the arguments or if you pass he wrong type of argument. I try passing the argument without conversion to date and I get the same error.

I check in Firebug and the template pass two argument to the view:

> Parameters: fecha 12/15/2014 submit   Submit

I don't know if this correct or this is the error.

I can execute without any issue store procedure that doesn't need arguments. My problem is with the procedure who need a date as argument.

Comment: Can you manually execute the stored procedure with the parameter you're passing in?

Comment: What are the parameters the stored procedure is expecting?

Comment: Yes I can execute the stored procedure manually and the store procedure expect a Date as parameter